# How to import one route response in another route in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I know this question might have been asked many times but i couldn't find a suitable answer. I have 2 routes-

```
router.post('/dbCall',async (req, res) => {
async function getStudent(id,data){
...
res.status(200).send(data)
}
})

module.exports = router
```

And second -

```
router.post('/getCourse', async(req,res) => {

const cid = // I want to assign route 1's response i.e data here.
})
module.exports = router
```

How can I assign the response (data) from route 1 to 2? Both are in different files and not sure how to import it.

Comment: Extract route 1  into a separate function and call it from route 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `middleware` like session. just create the value and assign to `res`

**Explanation**

1. [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) means its will execute before the route call. You canadd or check the value inside this
2. `next` will allow the access to next route
3. You need to lineup or call the `middle-ware` before the route call
4. Eg: if you access the user information from db. you need to know the session of use information. That information passed from client via token. At the time each call you need to decode the token.
5. At the time `middleware` do this job and assign the value to `res` object
6. same like you could any like this with your custom `middleware`.

> You should call the middleware before the route call

**middleware**

```
router.use(async (req, res,next) => {
  res.customVar = "something" // create
  next()
})
```

Then you could call from another route

**2nd route**

```
router.post('/getCourse', async(req,res) => {

const customVar = res.customerVar //read

const cid = // I want to assign route 1's response i.e data here.
})
```

Comment: Thanks @prasanth, but can you explain the solution? So where did the route / dbCall go? Because all these routes are in different folders. Also  there are several other routes, how does route 1 [router.use] know to go to route 2 and not others?

Comment: @minsuga i have updated with explanation. please check out the marked link also

Comment: Thanks @prasanth for the explanation, helped me a lot.